# photos on phone and onedrive

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onedrive, photos, blu-win-hd

When I make pictures by my phone, I can see them clicking **Photos** icon on phone, and also pictures are synchronized with **Camera Roll** folder on onedrive.

I want to keep pictures on onedrive, but remove from phone. So I created new folder inside onedrive **Pictures** and moved pictures there.

Them I deleted one picture from phone and it was deleted from this new folder, which I don't want.

What I want:

1. Keep pictures on onedrive.
2. Pictures made by phone should go to **Camera Roll**.
3. When I have enough pictures in this folder, I copy them to another folder on onedrive and remove from phone.

So I want Photos on phone being synchronized only with **Camera Roll** folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictures on your device and one drive are linked. You can unlink them.

For example for particular image:

- press image
- press ... on right down corner
- press File info

[image]

You see the same image on your device and on the onedrive.

You can unlink them and then delete image from your phone.